NRQL: Continuous graph for LATEST query
Background
I have a job that reports the status of a dependency when the status changes. So it reports 0 if it goes down, and 1 when it goes back up. But it reports very rarely because the dependency is stable.
The NRQL:
FROM SomeEvent
SELECT `service-status`

Shows a table
timestamp | service-status
--------------------------
...       | 1
...       | 1

I have the NRQL:
FROM SomeEvent
SELECT latest(`service-status`)
TIMESERIES

But this just produces a graph with dots at the times of reporting.

Desired outcome
Instead of the dots, I'd like to have a line that indicates that the status is still 1, even if no new reports have ticked in.
In other words, it should "fill" the gaps with whatever the latest value is.

You could make use of new-relic filter in here,
FROM SomeEvent
SELECT filter(latest(`service-status`), where true)
TIMESERIES


Thanks for the tip! But this now just produces one dot.

may be you could skip latest in here.
